# Need help improving the architecture of a functional command system

Tags: c#, concurrency, async-await

Given a set of commands whose Execute() method can be called concurrently, is there a way to unit test the command classes to ensure that other maintainers of the code don't add member data (other than readonly members passed to the constructor)?

Example:
When the code starts, create a mapping between scripted actions and commands that can service the action:

```
actionCommandTable = 
[“Translate”, new TranslateCommand(appcontext)],
[“Scale”, new ScaleCommand(appcontext)],
[“Assignment” new AssignmentCommand(appcontext, expressionEvaluator)]
```

Then at runtime:

```
actionCommandTable[“Translate”].Execute(actionDataContext);
```

The translate command:

```
public class TranslateAction : ActionCommand {
        //read-only interface
        private readonly AliasProvider aliasMap;
        //bad - need to prevent this instance from being added - will be overwritten unexpectedly
        private int transientValue; 
        public TranslateAction(IAppContext appContext) {
            aliasMap = appContext.AliasMap;
        }
        public override async Task Execute(ActionDataContext actionDataContext) {
            //assign to transientValue
            //do some work
            //await an animation
            //do more work
            //read from transientValue
        }

    }
```

In this example, all the work in Execute is ok if it doesn't work on shared members.

actionDataContext is intended to be the target of transient statefull data.

Comment: This sounds like you'd be better of with a Roslyn analyzer than a unit test.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflection to ensure all fields and properties are read only. However for validating if assignments are correct, you may have to validate command value assignment based on your requirement

```
    public void ValidateAllFieldsAreInitOnly(Type sut)
    {
        foreach(var field in sut.GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                     BindingFlags.Instance |
                                     BindingFlags.Static |
                                     BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            Assert.IsTrue(field.IsInitOnly);
        }

        foreach (var property in sut.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                     BindingFlags.Instance |
                                     BindingFlags.Static |
                                     BindingFlags.Public))
        {
            // returns true if the property has a set accessor, even if the accessor is private, internal 
            Assert.IsFalse(property.CanWrite);

            // OR can use depending on requirement

            // The MethodInfo object representing the Set method for this property if the set accessor is public, or null if the set accessor is not public.
            Assert.IsNull(property.GetSetMethod());
        }
    }
```

Note this will not catch scenarios when someone declare property as read only however initialize it in wrong manner ex -

Test will be **green** for

```
public class GoodCommand
{

    private readonly string privateField1;

    private readonly string privateField2;
    public GoodCommand(string field1, string field2)
    {
        privateField1 = field1;
        privateField2 = field2;
    }
}
```

Test will catch **(red)**

```
public class BadCommand
{

    private readonly string privateField1;

    private string privateField2;
    public BadCommand(string field1)
    {
        privateField1 = field1;
        privateField2 = "testingbadCommand";
    }
}
```

For this case test is green because proper assignment checking may vary based on requirement. You can catch this scenario also by validating if value assigned is as expected.

```
public class SmartBadCommand
{
    private readonly string privateField1;

    private readonly string privateField2;
    public SmartBadCommand(string field1)
    {
        privateField1 = field1;
        privateField2 = "testingbadCommand";
    }
}
```

Hope this help.